# Java example to query XML stream / string using BaseX

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

I trying to write  Java code to use BaseX in local mode to query XML returned by hitting a web service.

I'm not sure about the different ways of passing the XML. Should I

1. bind an external variable with XML data and pass to XQuery, and then use `fn:parse()`,
2. use the `fetch` module,
3. or is there any other better way of doing it?

Is there any other XQuery 3.0  processor with similar capabilities and in built modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution 1: Binding an external variable

This means you will first have to store the XML data as java variable and then pass it on to BaseX. You can certainly do so, it will look something like that:

```
declare variable $t as xs:string external;
parse-xml($t)
```

#### Solution 2: Use fetch()

`fetch:text()` and `fetch:binary()` are streamable, but `parse-xml` will materialize the string (be careful, the function is called `parse-xml()` not `parse()` as stated in your question.

```
parse-xml(fetch:text("YOUR-URI"))
```

#### Solution 3: Getting the data directly within XQuery

You can also simply retrieve your data from the web service using the http module:

```
http:send-request(<http:request method='get'></http:request>, "YOUR-URI")[2]
```

Solution 3 seems to me the easiest way, if you don't further need this result in the Java code. Otherwise you might want to stick to solution 1.

Comment: How do I make an XML doc from the request fetched, I don't find any documentation about that in BaseX. Would it be possible for you to share a small code snippet how to run XQuery on the data fetched using http:send-request. Thanks a lot dirkk !!

Comment: @user268203 The data will already be parsed and be valid XML, i.e. you can do XQuery/XPath expression, e.g. `(http:send-request(<http:request method='get'></http:request>, "YOUR-URI")[2])//div` gives you all `div` elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot !  In some of the services I am facing "Content is not allowed in prolog" may be a UTF-8 BOM issue, how can I overcome that ?

Comment: @Tirtha You have to include tagsoup to parse HTML (which is often invalid XML and can lead to this error messsage). See https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Parsers#HTML_Parser for more details